# Why I cannot use a global variable in a class PYTHON?

Tags: python

As below codes showed, I defined a global variable first, then I want to use it in a class, but failed.

```py
__var = 10

def test01():
    return __var

r1 = test01()
# 10


class Test:
    def test02(self):
        return __var

r2 = Test().test02()
# NameError: name '_Test__var' is not defined
```

Isn't `__var` a global variable? why I get error in second demo?

```py
_Test__var = 10

class Test:
    def test02(self):
        return __var

r2 = Test().test02()
# 10 worked as I defined `_Test__var = 10` as error showed
```

Comment: not sure why, but the problem does not occur if you remove the two underscores, or even one of them

Comment: Double underscore means the variable is "private". In quotation marks, because in Python nothing is really private, it's just access gets reaaally complicated. I don't know how to access such module-level (file-level aka global) variables, but for classes it works like your error shows (if you want to use it outside the class, you use `_ClassNameHere__variable`).

Comment: And it shows that error because obviously it doesn't see `__var` normally because of those protections. So it assumes it's something within that class (hence it seeks `_Test__var`), but it doesn't exist anyway, so it throws the error.

Comment: The issue here is that when you try access `__var` inside `Test`, you are trying to access mangled variable name. Variables with two `__` are being mangled (it's a sort of `privacy` by mangling). You can still access global variable with: `globals()['__var']`